# Please help query this database to get SUM point

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have table:

| nimhstrkrs | thsmstrkrs | kdkmktrkrs | sksmktrkrs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20522001 | 20212 | CODEA | 2 |
| 20522001 | 20212 | CODEB | 3 |
| 20522001 | 20212 | CODEC | 4 |
| 20522001 | 20211 | CODED | 2 (double) |
| 20522001 | 20212 | CODED | 2 (double) |
| 20522001 | 20212 | CODEE | 2 |
| 20522002 | 20211 | CODEZ | 5 (double) |
| 20522002 | 20212 | CODEZ | 5 (double) |
| 20522002 | 20212 | CODEB | 3 |
| 20522002 | 20212 | CODEC | 4 |
| 20522002 | 20212 | CODED | 2 |
| 20522002 | 20212 | CODEE | 2 |

I need result the double data only one in the sum:

$this-> getskstotal('20522001') result:   13
$this-> getskstotal('20522002') result:   16

My controller in codeigniter v3 is:

```
public function getskstotal($nim)
{
        $query = $this->db->query("select SUM(sksmktrkrs) as skstotal FROM rtrkrs WHERE nimhstrkrs = '".$nim."' GROUP BY kdkmktrkrs");
        foreach($query->result() as $value){
            $sks = $value->skstotal;
        }
        return $sks;    
}
```

but the result is not the same i need.

Answer (score 0):

You should distinct the results first and then make the sum.

```
select sum(sksmktrkrs) 
from (selec distinct nimhstrkrs, sksmktrkrs  from rtrkrs  WHERE nimhstrkrs = '".$nim."') 
GROUP BY kdkmktrkrs
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work for you:
[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9fiZoeek)

```
select
    sum("sksmktrkrs") 
from
    (
        select distinct
            "nimhstrkrs",
            "kdkmktrkrs",
            "sksmktrkrs" 
        from
            rtrkrs 
        WHERE
            "nimhstrkrs" = '".$nim."'
    )
;
```